# Arduino Ethernet Shield Not Assigning Correct IP Address

Tags: arduino

I've purchased two of the Arduino Ethernet Shields made by Arduino. I am using the Arduino Uno for my project. I cannot seem to assign an IP address to the shield. When I run the following code I receive 0.253.253.253 as the IP for one of the shields, and for the other one I receive 0.15.15.15 with the exact same code. I have no Idea what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {  0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x10, 0x30, 0x71 };

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,22);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // disable SD card if one in the slot
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  delay(5000);

  Serial.println("Starting w5100");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both the boards are connected on the same network then they can't have the same IP address, change the address of one of the boards.

edit :
Check if it is indeed starting up properly

```
if(!Ethernet.begin(mac, ip))
    Serial.println("failed");
else
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIp());
```

Also try it without the ip, to check if your router can assign the ip address.

Comment: They are not. I only have one Arduino Uno and two Sheilds. I tested the code on both shields with the same arduino uno and had different IP results. The router I am connected to has a gateway of 192.168.1.1 by the way.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question. Once you connect the arduino to the network can you see it on the router's connected devices page ?

Comment: No. I cannot ping the device either.

Comment: Doesn't look like it's starting up then,

Comment: Would this be an issue with the Arduino Uno then? I've tried two different ip shields with the same uno.

Comment: Possible, have you checked all the connections properly ? Also check edit

Comment: Yes I have checked the connections. What do you mean check edit?

Comment: When utilizing DHCP, it's as if the Ethernet.begin(mac); call never finishes and it hangs.

Comment: I think I will just order another uno.